# What is the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$? (Not [$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)!)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! Please share your insights on the questions with us. What have you tried ? If you don't have any clue, can you explain in a few words what you know about the Fourier transform ? Doing this will decuplate the chances that someone gets interested in your questions and helps you ! :)

Answer (score 2):

$x/\sin x$ is not an integrable function, so that the Fourier transform is not defined. Moreover it is not locally integrable, so that the Fourier transform is not defined even as distribution.